# Reg ex to allow only alphanumeric and some other special characters using form input fields?

Tags: jquery, regex

Hi all i like to allow only certain characters by user in form fields like a-z, A-Z, 0-9, -,& and _.

I am poor at regex. what will be the regex function to check whether string contains other than these characters using jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[a-z0-9\-&_]+$/i
```

And in use:

```
/^[a-z0-9\-&_]+$/i.test(value); // = true|false
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/37kkK/)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What is `/i`?

Comment: If you put `-` at the end of the character class, you wouldn't need to escape it `^[a-z0-9&_-]+$/i`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\w` for letters, digits and underscore as:

```
^[\w&-]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

just this

```
  ^[A-Za-z0-9\-_&]+$

^ Start of string
Char class [A-Za-z0-9\-\_] 1 to infinite times [greedy] matches:
    A-Z A character range between Literal A and Literal Z
    a-z A character range between Literal a and Literal z
    0-9 A character range between Literal 0 and Literal 9
    \-_& One of the following characters -_&
$ End of string
```

Or Even  `^[\w\d\-_&]+$`

```
^ Start of string
Char class [\w\d\-\_] 1 to infinite times [greedy] matches:
    \w Word character [a-zA-Z_\d]
    \d Digit [0-9]
    \-_& One of the following characters -_&
$ End of string
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `&` and `_`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
function isValid(str) {
    return (/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-&]+$/gi).test(str);
}
```

and test it like:

```
console.log(isValid('aA0_-&'));   // true
console.log(isValid('test*'));    // false
```